# Why it is returning an empty array while it has content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, css-selectors, web-scraping, nokogiri

I am trying to get auto-corrected spelling from Google's home page using Nokogiri.

For example, if I am typing "hw did" and the correct spelling is "how did", I have to get the correct spelling.

I tried with the `xpath` and `css` methods, but in both cases, I get the same empty array.

I got the XPath and CSS paths using FireBug.

Here is my Nokogiri code:

```
@requ=params[:search]
@requ_url=@requ.gsub(" ","+")  //to encode the url(if user inputs space than it should be convet into + )
@doc=Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=#{@requ_url}"))

binding.pry
```

Here are my XPath and CSS selectors:

Using XPath:

```
pry(#<SearchController>)> @doc.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/p/a").inspect
=> "[]"
```

Using CSS:

```
pry(#<SearchController>)> @doc.css('html body#gsr.srp div#main div#cnt.mdm div.mw div#rcnt div.col div#center_col div#taw div div.med p.ssp a.spell').inner_text()
=> ""
```

Comment: You are probably using a wrong xpath, firebug might have modified the html try the below, not tested though but was copied from chrome developer tools
`//*[@id="gsr"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/span` btw you should not rely on google for something like this or in the manner you are doing it they can change their design tomorrow without informing you

Comment: Why do you have `<br>` tags in your examples? Did you add them, or did you copy from some HTML source?

Comment: @tin man,no i don't have any br tag in my example,here just to format my question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Ah. They don't work in the code/pre formatting.

Answer (score 0):

First, use the right tools to manipulate URLs; They'll save you headaches.

Here's how I'd find the right spelling:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'uri'
require 'open-uri'

requ = 'hw did'
uri = URI.parse('https://www.google.co.in/search')
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form({'q' => requ})
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(uri.to_s)) 
doc.at('a.spell').text # => "how did"
```

---

> it works fine with "how did",check it with "bnglore" or any one word string,it gives an error. the same i was facing in my previous code. it is showing undefined method `text'

It's not that hard to figure out. They're changing the HTML so you have to change your selector. "Inspect" the suggested word "bangalore" and see where it exists in relation to the previous path. Once you know that, it's easy to find a way to access the word:

```
doc.at('span.spell').next_element.text # => "bangalore"
```

Don't trust Google to do things the easy way, or even the best way, or be consistent. Just because they return HTML one way for words with spaces, doesn't mean they're going to do it the same way for a single word. *I* would do it consistently, but they might be trying to discourage you from mining their pages so don't be surprised if you see variations.

Now, you need to figure out how to write code that knows when to use one selector/method or the other. That's for you to do.

Comment: it works fine with "how did",check it with "bnglore" or any one word string,it gives an error.
the same i was facing in my previous code.
it is showing undefined method `text'